# Confusion about how pointers are declared in C

Tags: c, pointers

The syntax commonly used in C to initialize pointers is

```
int *p = &x;
```

where `p` is our pointer and `x` is a previously declared variable. I unfortunately don't understand this syntax: `*p` is *not* equal to `&x`, but is instead equal to `x`. So why isn't the correct syntax

```
int *p = x;?
```

Does the compiler simply make an exception to the normal rules of variable assignment when dealing with pointers?

Comment: The thing to remember is that this is initialisation, not assignment.  The syntax is similar, but only superficially so.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth do you mind clarifying the difference between initialisation and assignment? I'm new to C and thought they were the same thing.

Comment: `int *p = &x;` is the same as `int *p;` followed by `p = &x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C declaration syntax is admittedly confusing. It *generally* follows the rule that "declaration follows use", but that's not a hard and fast rule.

The type name `int*` means "pointer to `int`", but to define an object `p` of type "pointer to `int`", we don't simply write that type name followed by the name of the object:

```
int* p;
```

Instead, we write:

```
int *p;
```

which means that `*p` is of type `int`; it follows from that that `p` must be of type `int*`.

You've probably noticed that both declarations are the same except for the spacing -- and the compiler doesn't care about spacing.  In fact, some programmers prefer to write `int* p;`, even though it doesn't strictly follow the grammar, because it's clearer in this case.

The distinction becomes important if you want to define multiple objects in a single declaration:

```
int *p, *q;
```

means that `*p` and `*q` are both of type `int`.  And

```
int *x, y;
```

means that `*x` and `y` are of type `int` -- which means that `x` is an `int*` and `y` is an `int`.  Programmers who prefer to place the `*` next to the `int` need to split this up into two lines (which is a good idea anyway).

So for an object declaration, the extra specifiers are associated with the name being defined, not with the type. But an initializer applies to the newly created object.  So this:

```
int *p;
```

means that `*p` is of type `int`, but this:

```
int *p = &x;
```

means that `p` itself is initialized with the value `&x`.

I won't try to argue that this is how C's declaration syntax *should* have been defined. It has its own consistent logic to it, but it's caused a lot of confusion. But it is the way it is.

Comment: So long story short: the compiler first sees `int *p` and creates a variable `p`  which points to an integers; next, the compiler sees the `=` sign and prepares to assign a value to the most recently created variable, which is `p`; finally, the compiler assigns the value `&x` to `p`. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @AlessandroPower: That's the basic idea, though in practice things aren't likely to happen in that order. Typically a compiler will parse the entire source file, following the rules in the language grammar, producing some compiler-specific intermediate form. After some more processing, it traverses the intermediate form, generating executable code and entries in its internal symbol table. (I've probably managed to simultaneously oversimplify and overcomplicate it.)

Answer (score 3):

read it this way

```
int* p = &x;
```

ie int* is a type - a pointer to an int;

Comment: The convention you use is much for intuitive I find, but I'm trying to understand the `int *p` convention, which just seems like it shouldn't work...

Comment: @AlessandroPower C doesnt care about spaces, both mean exactly the same thing. I can just as validly say `int * p` or `int      *    p`

Comment: The `int *p` convention makes it much clearer that the `*` is more closely associated with `p` than it is with `int`.  For example, `int* p,q;` defines 'p' as an `int *` while q is a plain `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` character has a different meaning depending on where you find it. I can think of three meaning off the top of my head:

#### 1. In a declaration

```
int *x;
```

Here, we are writing a variable declaration. We are creating a variable named `x` with type `int *`.

#### 2. As a dereference in an expression

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
int y = *x;
```

Here we are using the same token but note that it is now inside an expression! (The right hand side of the equal sign is an expression). Here it means dereference.

#### 3. As multiplication

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
int y = *x * *x;
```

Here we are using the same character for multiplication!

#### So what gives?

The compiler is able to use the context around the `*` character to determine which of these three cases we are in. It's certainly arguable that we should have different characters to represent these three things, but that's not the language that we have.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to your declaration.

```
int *p = &x;
```

Let's take the first half. The "int *p" tells the compiler that the variable 'p' has a location in memory as a value and it should be interpreted as an 'int'. The second half, '&x', means to get me the location in memory of the variable x. So you can save 'location in memory of variable x' into a variable that represents 'location in memory.'

A real world analogy would be if you have houses on a street, each with an address (one of the houses would be 'x' in your example), and you also have a postcard, 'p,' on which you can write the address of a house. You can't put the house, x, on the postcard. You can only put the address of the house, &x, on the postcard.

Answer (score 0):

`int *p = &x;`

When prefixed with a `*` in a declaration, an identifier is defined to be a pointer to the given type.  For example, `p` is a pointer to `x`;  Read it like this:

- declare a pointer to an `int` called `p`
- to the pointer `p`, assign the following value: `the address of x`

If we want to use `p` to get the value of `x`, we do what is called dereferencing: `*p`

For example:

```
int x = 35;
int *p = &x;
printf("x = %d\n", *p); // Prints x = 35
printf("%p\n", p); // Prints the address of x (which is the same as the value of p)
printf("%p\n", &p); // Prints the address of the variable p
```

Answer (score 0):

int x = 5; // Declaring an integer 'x' and initializing it with the value 5.

int *p1 = &x; // Declaring Pointer 'p1' & Initializing it with address of 'x'.

printf("x = %d\n", *p1); // De-referencing Pointer 'p1' to get value of 'x'.

int *p2 = NULL; // Declaraing a Pointer to an int. Initialize it to NULL.

p2 = &x; // Assigning address of 'x' to pointer 'p2'.

printf("x = %d\n", *p2); // De-referencing Pointer 'p2' to get value of 'x'.